# Cancel eclipse plugin job

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, processbuilder

I run in a eclipse plugin `Job` a process that performs long operations without much output.
I want to be able to cancel the `Job` if users request it, but with the implementation bellow, the `Job` is not stopping unless the process prints something to the output stream.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
                (new InputStreamReader(
                        process.getInputStream(), UTF_8_CHARSET)));

while (scanner.hasNext())
{

    if (monitor.isCanceled() {
        // user canceled the job, destroy the process to return
        process.destroy();
        break;
    }

    CONSOLE.getStream().println(scanner.nextLine());

}

try {
    process.waitFor();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

    Activator.log(ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);

} finally {
    process.destroyForcibly();
}
```

Do I have other options to handle the cancelling of the job and to stop the process faster instead of waiting for a new line feed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the code reading the process output stream in to a separate thread and in your main loop just wait for the process to end with a short timeout so you can check for canceled.

So the main code would be something like:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();

// Read standard output
new StreamConsumer(process.getInputStream()).start();

// You should also always read stderr
new StreamConsumer(process.getErrorStream()).start();

// Wait for process to end and check for cancel

while (!process.waitFor(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
  if (monitor.isCanceled() {
    // user canceled the job, destroy the process to return
    process.destroy();
    break;
  }
}
```

And `StreamConsumer` is something like:

```
public class StreamConsumer extends Thread
{
  private final InputStream _input;

  public StreamConsumer(final InputStream inputStream)
  {
    super();

    _input = inputStream;

    setDaemon(true);
  }


  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    // TODO your code to read the stream
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution, Greg! A friend of mine came with a solution to have another thread with a constructor `MonitorCancelThread( Process process, IProgressMonitor monitor)` and in the `run` method to have something like: `while (true) { if (monitor.isCancelled()) { process.destroy; break;}}` but your solutoin is cleaner and more logical from an architecture perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `Scanner` use a `BufferedReader` which provides the `ready` method which is a non-blocking way of telling you if there is something to read instead of using Scanner's `nextLine()` which is blocking until something is actually read.

Small example implementation:

```
volatile static boolean stop = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    // Create a new thread that reads input from System.in
    new Thread(() -> {

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (!stop)
        {
            try
            {
                // If there is something to read read it and print it
                if (read.ready())
                {
                    System.out.println(read.readLine());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // Do some handling...
            }
        }

    }).start();

    // Wait 5 seconds then stop the thread by making the flag false.
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    stop = true;
}
```

Your flag is obviously provided with the Process. The take away is to use a non-blocking operation (a peek if there is actually something to print) instead of using a blocking operation.

Comment: I could have used a `BufferedReader` directly in the `Scanner` so it could have been `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        process.getInputStream(), UTF_8_CHARSET))));`, but that still wouldn't have gave me a better option

Answer (score 0):

In my case i didn't know how long the process is going. So a timeout was no option.
My alternative solution is to start a separate monitor thread that is watching the state of the `IProgressMonitor`. If the progress monitor is in the canceled state then the executing thread is interupted.

```java
public static void startMonitorThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {        
    final Thread runThread = Thread.currentThread();                     
    new Thread("Monitor") {                                              
        @Override                                                        
        public void run() {                                              
            while (runThread.isAlive() && !monitor.isCanceled()) {       
                try {                                                    
                    Thread.sleep(100);                                   
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {               
                    break;                                               
                }                                                        
            }                                                            
            if (runThread.isAlive()) {                                   
                runThread.interrupt();                                   
            }                                                            
        };                                                               
    }.start();                                                           
}
```

The next snippet shows a example how this can be used:

```java
startMonitorThread(monitor);                                                                       

final Process process = new ProcessBuilder("...").start();                                         
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    while (process.isAlive()) {                                                                    
        if (reader.ready()) {                                                                      
            final String line = reader.readLine();                                                 
            // ... do something with line                                                          
        } else {                                                                                   
            Thread.sleep(10);                                                                      
        }                                                                                          
    }                                                                                              
}
```

First i did the same mistake to use a scanner that is blocking (and the interuption didn't worked). Like the answer of Ben is mentioning it is better to use a `BufferedReader` and the non blocking `ready()` method to check if there is more to read.